# Regex whitespace word boundary

Tags: regex

I have this expression

```
\b[A-Za-z]+\b
```

If I give `abc@de mnop`, it matches `abc`, `de` and `mnop`, but I want it to match only `mnop`. How can I do that?

Comment: You could be more specific about what you want to match, maybe use whitespace and punctuation as the delimiter rather than a word boundary.

Comment: you need to specify the language/tool..regex implementation differs across languages

Comment: Please prefer [Qtax answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601639/3832970) as it is more portable since some regex flavors require lookbehind patterns to be of fixed length.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\b` is a word boundary.

So, `\b` is similar to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` i.e `\b` would **check** for anything except `word`

You can instead use this regex

```
(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s|$)
-------- --------- ------
   |         |       |->match only if the pattern is followed by a space(\s) or end of string/line($)
   |         |->pattern
   |->match only if the pattern is preceded by space(\s) or start of string\line(^)
```

Comment: @BoristheSpider would you have a version of this that can run in JavaScript?

Comment: Note that some regex engines like `re` in Python do not support variable length look-behind: `(?<=\s|^)`. There you have to match `^` outside of look-behind: `(?:^|(?<=\s))` or use the much simpler solution by Qtax: `(?<!\S)`

Answer (score 11):

`\b` means `(?:(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))`. Which would match positions between letters and `@`.

You can write:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z]+(?!\S)
```

`(?!\S)` is equivalent to `(?=\s|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Regex word boundary doen't match(\b) matching and whitespace`

Only white in sample is

```
abc@de mnop   
      ^
```

Try `\s([A-Za-z]+)\b`

where `\s` is the anchor, not a boundry at all