# How to count words in a textarea if the word has a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text input and a text area.  I want to count the number of times the text input value occurs in the text area.  The following code works fine when the text input value doesn't have any spaces before or after.  But when it has spaces, I'm getting a null even if it occurs in the text area.  For example:

```
text input value: "dog"
text area value: "dog"
I get "1" in the console log.
```

However

```
text input value: "dog_"
text area value: "dog_"
I get "null" in the console log.
```

How do I get it so if I type  "dog_" in the text input and there is a  "dog_" in the text area, the count will be "1"

```
function testCount() {

var textVal = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
var textArea = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + textVal + "\\b",'gi');
var count = textArea.match(regex).length;

console.log(count);

}
```

I've tried various RegExp but they didn't solve the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the underscore supposed to be a space?

Comment: @Johnny Mopp Yes

Comment: @rock star The underscore is a supposed to be a space.  Try your fiddle with a space, and you'll see that you don't get a "1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function testCount() {

  var textVal = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
  var textArea = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
  var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\b)" + textVal + "(\\b|\\W|$)",'gi');  // UPDATE: Added "\\W"
  var count = textArea.match(regex);
  
  // To stop function if input is empty
  if (!textVal) return;
  
  // To prevent no-match cases from generating error
  if (!count)
    count = 0;
  else
    count = count.length;

  console.log(count);

}
```

```html
<input id="textInput" type="text" oninput="testCount()">
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```

**UPDATE**

[@rockstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8897421/rock-star) suggested an even better RegExp.

```
new RegExp("(^|[^\\w ])(" + textVal + ")([^\\w ]|$)",'gi')
```

Unlike the previous implementation, this RegExp ensures perfect match (including trailing spaces).

If you feel confused with the complicated symbols, feel free to look at a very simple reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

**UPDATE 2**

[@rockstar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8897421/rock-star) again suggested an even better RegExp.

```
new RegExp("(^|[^\\w ])" + textVal + "(?=[^\\w ]|$)",'gi');
```

Comment: This is close, but it seems to fail in some cases. For example `foo .`

Comment: Nice, seems like that'll work for the OP. It captures the character after but he appears to only want a count, so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Yong Quan This almost does what I need.  One problem though, is that if there is "dog(space)" or "(space)dog" in the textarea and "dog" no spaces in the input box, then I get a match when I shouldn't.

Comment: @user3080392: Why should that not be counted as a match? If the `input` has `"dog"` and the `textarea` has `dog` with a space before or after it, there still is a match. I think you need to define exactly what your criteria is before anyone can really help you.

Comment: @rock star One of my criteria is that the beginning and trailing space should be considered part of the word.  So, dog(space) and (space)dog should be considered different from dog no spaces.

Comment: @user3080392: Yes, but what is the rest of your criteria. Are there any other characters that should be considered an unbroken part of the word in the textarea? It's impossible to give an accurate answer if you don't describe the problem in full.

Comment: @rock star At this point, that's really the last criterion I'm trying to achieve.  If I could figure out a regex that can recognize a word with its surrounding space as a unique entity, I'd be fine. Thanks.

Comment: @user3080392: I'm sure Yong Quan will be able to come up with something when he returns. If it were me, I'd wouldn't use a regex, at least not for the entire thing. Instead I'd do just a plain old text match, and then manually check the characters before and after the match to see if they should be accepted as a word boundary of your definition.

Comment: `var regex = new RegExp("(^|[^\\w ])(" + textVal + ")([^\\w ]|$)",'gi');` Deleted my previous comment because I thought it was wrong, but it was right, I believe. But again, Yong Quan may have something better.

Comment: @rock star Yes, it worked for me too.  Good job!  You should write it as an answer so I can give you credit.  Maybe also an explanation of the regex in plain English too.  The symbols get a bit confusing.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3080392: I was really just building on this answer, so he can feel free to add it here if he wants to. The regex basically just look for `[^\w ]` on either side of your search term, which will match anything that's neither a word character nor a space. However, I just realized that it doesn't find all matches in all cases, because the "boundary" characters are themselves consumed, so a single boundary character can't account for both the end of one match and the start of another. This `"dog .dog "` should result in `2` but doesn't.

Comment: @rockstar, I dont have anything better, thanks for having faith in me mate ;)

Comment: Ah, here we go. It just needed a positive lookahead. `new RegExp("(^|[^\\w ])" + textVal + "(?=[^\\w ]|$)",'gi');` So now `"dog "` will find two in `"dog .dog "`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Regex word boundaries `\b` in your regex but word boundaries do not include preceding *or* proceeding trailing spaces.

As stated in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601608/4988637);

> `\b` is similar to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` i.e `\b` would **check** for anything except
>   `word`

This post also shows an alternative to word boundaries for searching including preceding *and* proceeding trailing spaces.

**Try changing**

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + textVal + "\\b",'gi');
```

**to**

```
var regex = new RegExp("(?<=\s|^)" + textVal + "(?=\s|$)", 'gi');
```

**or even**

```
var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\s|$)" + textVal + "(?:^|\s|$)", 'gi');
```

The third code snippet is not as strict as the second one, but may be a little more compatible if you have issues with the second snippet.

---

*Here is a working example:*

```js
function testCount() {
  var textVal = document.getElementById("textInput").value;
  var textArea = document.getElementById("textArea").value;
  var regex = new RegExp("(?<=\s|^)" + textVal + "(?=\s|$)", 'gi');
  var match = textArea.match(regex);
  var count = match ? match.length : 0;

  console.log(count);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", testCount);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textInput">
<button id="btn">
  Count
</button>
<textarea id="textArea"></textarea>
```

Comment: You lost the word boundaries.

Comment: But now `foo` will match against `foobar`. I think the boundaries are meant to do whole word (or phrase) matching, without including subsections of words.

Comment: rock star is right.  I want to keep the word boundaries.

Comment: Ah okay, I'll try to update my answer with word boundaries

Comment: *"word boundaries do not include spaces"* Unsure what you mean by that. Boundaries certainly include spaces, but maybe I'm missing your point.

Comment: Sorry but it's still not clear. A boundary by definition will be before or after the word. It seems like if the search term is `"foo "`, and the searched text has `"foo     "`, it should match the exact characters and then the space that comes after the first space.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error invalid regexp group using your snippet and with my own code.

Comment: Th really odd thing is that if the textarea has `"foo    x"`, the original code works.

Comment: @user3080392 I wonder if it's possible that my regex requires an updated browser like Google Chrome, because the snippet I wrote it working fine for me.

Comment: @Acidic: Both the search term and the target text have a trailing whitespace. I don't see why it wouldn't match. The `\b` should match against the end of the string.

Comment: @Acidic: Obviously it doesn't work. The question is why. Your solution isn't a replacement for a word boundary because it only counts spaces as boundaries. The explanation you gave doesn't explain why equal matching characters stop matching just because there's a space on the end.

Comment: @user3080392 `"(?:^|\s|$)"+textVal+"(?:^|\s|$)"` works, but is not as strict as my answer was, but it is more compatible I think. Should I update my answer with this if it works for you?

Comment: Your answer attempts to explain why, so I'm asking about your explanation. Literally. Your solution doesn't replicate a word boundary.

Comment: If you don't want someone to point out that your answer is wrong, don't post wrong answers.

Comment: @Acidic I'm still tinkering with it in my code, It seems to work, but I'm not sure yet.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I will. It helps people to not be misled by faulty information. Consider also that he's looking for a count. Yours will also fail to match multiple matches.

Comment: And yeah, go ahead and downvote my correct answers to other questions. It doesn't hurt me; it only hurts those who will be confused by your vote.  I'll never understand those who think they're above correction.