# Java Regex replace surrounding whitespace

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am using Elasticsearch which utilizes the Java Regex API, which supports grouping.

What I want to do is being able to surround letters that have a whitespace as optional prefix and mandatory suffix, with an underscore:

```
"e hello world" => "_e_ hello world" (doesn't work for my solution)
"hello e world" => "hello _e_ world" (works)
```

My solution is:

```
"pattern": "(?<=\\s)(e)(?=\\s)",
"replacement": " _$1_ "
```

How do I make the first lookbehind optional?

Comment: Making lookarounds optional makes no sense, it is equal to removing them. I think you want to match start and end of string positions, use `"pattern": "(?<!\\S)(e)(?!\\S)"`. Or even `"pattern": "(?<!\\S)e(?!\\S)"` => `"replacement": " _$0_ "`. Actually, the [answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15601639/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works like a charm. thank you!