# Unmatch complete words if a negative lookahead is satisfied

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to match only those words which doesn't have special characters like `@` and `:`.
For example:

1. `git@github.com` shouldn't match
2. `list` should return a valid match
3. `show` should also return a valid match

I tried it using a negative lookahead `\w+(?![@:])`

But it matches `gi` out of `git@github.com` but it shouldn't match that too.

Comment: You need to add boundaries, and if your string are complete lines you need to add anchors

Comment: [`^\w+(?![@:])$`](https://regex101.com/r/2ndFxP/1/) or [`(?<!\S)\w+(?![@:])(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/2ndFxP/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add `\w` to the lookahead:

```
\w+(?![\w@:])
```

The equivalent is using a word boundary:

```
\w+\b(?![@:])
```

Besides,  you may consider adding a left-hand boundary to avoid matching words inside non-word non-whitespace chunks of text:

```
^\w+(?![\w@:])
```

Or

```
(?<!\S)\w+(?![\w@:])
```

The `^` will match the word at the start of the string and `(?<!S)` will match only if the word is preceded with whitespace or start of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i09lAP/3).

**Why not `(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)`**, the [whitespace boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601563/regex-whitespace-word-boundary)? Because since you are building a lexer, you most probably have to deal with natural language sentences where words are likely to be followed with punctuation, and the `(?!\S)` negative lookahead would make the `\w+` match only when it is followed with whitespace or at the end of the string.

Comment: How did adding a \w inside lookahead work? I don't get it.

Comment: @AMANSHARMA It makes the match fail if there is a word char immediately to the right, so it acts as an unambiguous word boundary. You might use the original lookahead but you would need a possessive `++` after `\w` then, not a regular `+`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i09lAP/4).

Comment: By your first logic that it should fail when it find a character immediately to the right. How does it still match `list` or `show`? It has characters to the right of `l` or `s`.

Comment: @AMANSHARMA `\w+` matches one *or more* word chars, that is why.

Comment: I know that. But `gi` should also be matched by `\w+`? I am getting confused here.

Comment: @AMANSHARMA `(?<!\S)` matches either start of string or location in string that is immediately preceded with whitespace. Then, `\w+` grabs 1 or more word chars. Then, it tries the lookahead pattern. `(?![\w@:])` makes sure the next char is not a word, not `@` and not `:` chars. So, when there is `git@` match, the regex engine fails and *backtracks* to `gi` (`t` is discarded from the match as it is followed with `@`). However, since there is `t` after `gi` that it is a word char the whole match fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookbehind and negative lookahead patterns around a word pattern to make sure that the word is not preceded or followed by a non-space character, or in other words, to make sure that it is surrounded by either a space or a string boundary:

```
(?<!\S)\w+(?!\S)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cjhUUM/2

Comment: I am writing a lexer to highlight syntax. These words come in between of a command. Hence, I can't use anchor tags.